# Yesod database persistent record access

Tags: haskell, yesod

Below is in the `models` file

```
UserSetting
    source ArticleSourceId
    minimumShouldMatch Int 
    articleLength Int
    userId UserId
    deriving Show
```

In my handler, I found that I couldn't use for example `source` on the Entity Value `vVal`.

```
   (v:_) <- selectList [UserSettingUserId ==. asUd] [LimitTo 1]
   let vVal = source $ entityVal v
   let vId = entityKey v
```

Error message is `Variable not in scope: source :: UserSetting -> Integer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
let vVal = userSettingSource $ entityVal v
```